# Regular expression to select all whitespace that IS in quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex, textmate

For example:

`string text = 'some text "and some more" and some other "this is a second group" okay the end';`.

I'd like to capture all the spaces that are between quotation marks. The end goal is to replace those spaces with commas.

The end goal, for example:

```
'some text "and,some,more" and some other "this,is,a,second,group" okay the end'
```

For example, this would do what I'd like in javascript:

```
text.replace(/(["]).*?\1/gm, function ($0) {
    return $0.replace(/\s/g, ',');
});
```

Unfortunately, the only tool I have available is the find/replace feature of textmate.

I've found another that does the opposite of what I need, but uses one line like I need:

```
text.replace(/\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/gm, ',');
```

Thanks!

Comment: @shelvacu , So far all my tries have either returned nothing or the opposite of what I need. I'm not sure how to use the lookbehind to get beginning and end quotes and also look for text inside of them. 


`/(["]).*?\1/gm` found everything in quotes.


`/(["]).*?(\s)+?\2.*?\1/gm` and `/(["'])(?:(?=(\s?))\2.)*?\1/gm` just returned the same as above.

`/\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/gm` gives me the exact opposite of what I need.

Comment: Try `\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That did it thank you!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```
\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexr.com/3d862)

The `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace that is followed by an odd number of double quotes.

*Details*: The whitespace matching part is simple, the positive lookahead requires

- `(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*` - zero  or more sequences of 2 sequences matching 0+ characters other than a `"` and then a `"` (0+ `"..."`s)
- `[^"]*"[^"]*` - 0+ characters other than a `"` followed with a `"` and again followed with 0+ characters other than a `"` (an odd quote must be to the right of the currently matched whitespace)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Mind that this is more a workaround than a solution, this kind of job should  be done with some regular programming language, the way described in the question. Oh, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tX1gM4/1) worked again finally.